# Python: How can I create a "global object"?

Tags: python, sqlite, oop

I have a problem with the following code. As you can see I set up an sqlite3 database in the function `setup_session()`, though when I try to run it it throws an exception because the object `cursor` which I created in `setup_session()` is only available inside the function.

```
import sqlite3

def setup_session():
    db = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()


setup_session()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE subjects (subject text)")
```

How can I change it so that cursor is also available from outside the function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your question literally: add `global cursor` at the top of the function:

```
def setup_session():
    global cursor
    db = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
```

However `global` is **not** good programming practice and you can almost invariably use better style.  Here I would recommend:

```
def setup_session():
    db = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
    return db.cursor()

cursor = setup_session()
```

That is, avoid `global`: have the function `return` its result, rather than stashing it away into a global variable, and assign that result to whatever variable you want when you **call** the function.

This style generally allows better testing, better maintenance, less headaches, more flexibility (what if tomorrow you want **two** cursors in `cursor1` and `cursor2`, just for example? maintenance needed with globals, trivial with the better approach of `return`ing the result...).

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just return it?

```
def setup_session():
    db = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
    return db.cursor()
```